# Having a module and class with the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module stat that exists in the directory structure: lib/stat_creator/stat/

In lib/stat_creator/stat.rb I have the files in the lib/stat_creator/stat/ directory that I require, as well as:

```
module StatCreator
    module Stat
    end
end
```

When I use that module I refer to the classes as

```
StatCreator::Stat::Foo.new
```

Now I want a root Stat class that lives in app.  I've made my Stat class in app/models and set it up in routes.rb.  But if I go to rails console and try to use the Stat class in app/models like:

```
Stat.by_user_id("ID")
```

I get the error: LoadError: Expected ../lib/stat_creator/stat.rb to define Stat

I thought the point of using namespaces was to avoid this kind of conflict, so I don't understand what I"m doing wrong.

Comment: Are you by any chance doing `include StatCreator` in your `Stat` model?

Comment: I don't include StatCreator, but I do specify it as I've added above.  I think this has to be done though because I don't want to be able to call Stat::Foo.new since that would create a conflict with class Stat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd do:

```
::Stat.by_user_id("ID")
```